# Trying to pass jQuery plugin callback function to a controller function using a directive

Tags: angularjs

i'm using a jQuery plugin that implements some callbacks which I would like to use. I'm trying to send the callback function directly to the controller but the parameters are not sending properly.

Here's my code

```
flairApp.directive('fullpage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).fullpage({
                afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                    scope.afterLoad(anchorLink, index)
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and for the controller

```
angular.module('homeController', ['ngSanitize'])

.controller('homeController', function($scope, Blog, $stateParams) {

    $scope.afterLoad = function (anchorLink, index) {
        console.log(anchorLink);
    };

});
```

The html has the directive alone

```
<div fullpage></div>
```

It could be awesome if I could call the function using the directive instead like this:

```
<div fullpage after-load="afterload"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(element).fullpage()` takes an options object as its argument. In this options object, you have some options, like `afterLoad`. The function you pass to afterLoad is executed as a callback somewhere inside fullpage's stuff.

You can pass in a function to your directive with something like this in your directive defintion:

```
scope: {
  afterLoadCallback: '&' // this value is attached to scope.afterLoadCallback
}
```

The '&' means we're wanting to pass in a function. There are also '@' and '=' and they all behave slightly differently.

So...

```
flairApp.directive('fullpage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          afterLoadCallback: '&' // this value is attached to scope.afterLoad
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).fullpage({
                afterLoad: scope.afterLoadCallback // comes from function passed into directive in the view
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and in your view:

`<div fullpage after-load-callback="foo()"></div>` where `foo` is on the scope of the controller that controls the view where fullpage is being used.

Answer (score 0):

> It could be awesome if I could call the function using the directive instead like this:

```
<div fullpage after-load="afterload(anchorLink,index)"></div>
```

This can be done with an isolate scope in the directive

From the Docs:

`&` or `&attr` - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no `attr` name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given `<widget my-attr="count = count + value">` and widget definition of `scope: { localFn:'&myAttr' }`, then isolate scope property `localFn` will point to a function wrapper for the `count = count + value` expression. Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be  done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is `increment(amount)` then we can specify the amount value by calling the `localFn` as `localFn({amount: 22})`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#scope

Answer (score 0):

You could create an isolated scope and pass the callback function with `&` binding.

This [post](http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/11/06/passing-functions-to-angularjs-directives/) is also useful to understand how it works.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nr5ra3jd/).

I've also added the `anchors` binding so that `afterLoad` is returning somthing useful. Before this it returned `undefined`.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.callback = function(link, index) {
      console.log(link, index);
    };

    $scope.anchorLinks = ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage'];
  })
  .directive('fullpage', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        anchors: '=',
        afterLoad: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).fullpage({
          anchors: scope.anchors,
          afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
            scope.afterLoad({
              link: anchorLink,
              index: index
            });
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.6/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.6/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div fullpage after-load="callback(link,index)" anchors="anchorLinks">
    <div class="section">first section</div>
    <div class="section">second section</div>
    <div class="section">third section</div>
  </div>
</div>
```